# Maven Initialize on CI/CD

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, bitbucket

Hi I have added oracle jdbc jar to my spring boot project. The idea is the jar should be automatically added to m2. We should  run the project and take build. We followed the first method with automatic installation of jar.

```
http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/
```

It worked like a charm. But when we run it in bitbucket pipeline. We're getting oracle dependency not found error. Since the maven not getting initialized.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

         .....

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
       .......

</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-install-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.5,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                            <version>12.1.0.2</version>
                            <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            <file>${project.basedir}/lib/ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar</file>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
              ....
            </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I tried adding below -U when taking mvn build.But didn't work. Is it possible to trigger maven initialize from command?

```
mvn -U -f pom.xml clean install

mvn dependency:resolve -U
mvn -f pom.xml clean install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to have your own Nexus/Artifactory server on which you manage all your artifacts. Then you do not need to do local installs of artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with remote repository being called at the compilation via CI/CD pipeline, the dependency is available on your local required for compilation. I would recommend you to check the settings.xml for your centralized repository and check if the jar is available there. if you need to use maven central repo you can pass it as via maven command line parameters -Dmaven.repo.remote=http://remote-repo